# Typeguard with Jupyter (TensorFlow types)

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, typeguards

I'm using Typeguard 4.0.0, along with Jupyter 6.4.8 running Python 3.10.6.

Is this compatible with checking return types on functions, when the return types are TensorFlow types? Here's my function:

```
@typechecked
def make_neural_network(num_hidden_layers:int = 8, neurons_per_layer:int = 20) -> tf.keras.Model:
    model = tf.keras.Sequential()

    ...

    return model
```

This seems to work when I do Python directly from the command line. But when I run the Jupyter cell, I get a massive error stack trace:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_147999/4238726711.py in <module>
      3 
      4 @typechecked
----> 5 def make_neural_network(num_hidden_layers:int = 8, neurons_per_layer:int = 20) -> tf.keras.Model:
      6 
      7     # Initialize a feedforward neural network

~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/typeguard/_decorators.py in typechecked(target, forward_ref_policy, typecheck_fail_callback, collection_check_strategy, debug_instrumentation)
    211         target = target.__func__
    212 
--> 213     retval = instrument(target)
    214     if isinstance(retval, str):
    215         warn(

~/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/typeguard/_decorators.py in instrument(f)
     49 
     50     target_path = [item for item in f.__qualname__.split(".") if item != "<locals>"]
---> 51     module_source = inspect.getsource(sys.modules[f.__module__])
     52     module_ast = ast.parse(module_source)
     53     instrumentor = TypeguardTransformer(target_path)

/usr/lib/python3.10/inspect.py in getsource(object)
   1145     or code object.  The source code is returned as a single string.  An
   1146     OSError is raised if the source code cannot be retrieved."""
-> 1147     lines, lnum = getsourcelines(object)
   1148     return ''.join(lines)
   1149 

/usr/lib/python3.10/inspect.py in getsourcelines(object)
   1127     raised if the source code cannot be retrieved."""
   1128     object = unwrap(object)
-> 1129     lines, lnum = findsource(object)
   1130 
   1131     if istraceback(object):

/usr/lib/python3.10/inspect.py in findsource(object)
    938     is raised if the source code cannot be retrieved."""
    939 
--> 940     file = getsourcefile(object)
    941     if file:
    942         # Invalidate cache if needed.

/usr/lib/python3.10/inspect.py in getsourcefile(object)
    815     Return None if no way can be identified to get the source.
    816     """
--> 817     filename = getfile(object)
    818     all_bytecode_suffixes = importlib.machinery.DEBUG_BYTECODE_SUFFIXES[:]
    819     all_bytecode_suffixes += importlib.machinery.OPTIMIZED_BYTECODE_SUFFIXES[:]

/usr/lib/python3.10/inspect.py in getfile(object)
    776         if getattr(object, '__file__', None):
    777             return object.__file__
--> 778         raise TypeError('{!r} is a built-in module'.format(object))
    779     if isclass(object):
    780         if hasattr(object, '__module__'):

TypeError: <module '__main__'> is a built-in module
```

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong? I'd really like to be able to enforce types, since it helps me debug and understand the big picture of my code.